# Download list attachments using lists.asmx webservice

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying to download SharePoint list attachments using the following code. I am receiving an exception "Column 'Attachment_Text' does not belong to table Attachments". Please help resolve this.

```
private static void fnDownloadattachment(string id)
    {
        Reference.Lists myservice = new Reference.Lists();
        myservice.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        myservice.Url = "http://XXXXX/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";

        XmlNode node = myservice.GetAttachmentCollection("listname", id);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(node))
        {
            ds.ReadXml(reader);
        }

        DataTable dtAttachment = ds.Tables[0];

        for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt <= dtAttachment.Rows.Count - 1; iCnt++)
        {

            string sourceUrl = Convert.ToString(dtAttachment.Rows[iCnt]["Attachment_Text"]);

            int strLastIndx = sourceUrl.LastIndexOf(@"/");

            string FileName = sourceUrl.Substring(strLastIndx + 1);


            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {


                client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                byte[] response = client.DownloadData(sourceUrl);

                FileStream fStream = new FileStream(@"C:\DummyListAttachments\" + FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                fStream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
                fStream.Close();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't work only in case you have one attachment.

The best way to find a workaround is to look at the DataTable when you have only one attachment, and see what is the name of the column instead of "Attachment_Text".

You can do it like this:

```
foreach (DataColumn column in dtAttachment.Columns)
{
    Console.Write(column.ColumnName);
}
```

After you do this, just change "Attachment_Text" to the necessary column name.

Comment: Thanks. The column name was "Attachment". The code now works !